# Automatic pdf_tex export from svg via inkscape and svg package on Windows

Tags: pdftex, svg, shell-escape, inkscape

I have the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\setsvg{inkscape=inkscape -z -D, inkscapeversion=1, svgpath=figures/}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Running the code example in TexStudio with `txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]` results in the following error:

`Package svg Error: File 'fig_svg-tex.pdf' is missing. \includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig}`

The image's path is `./figures/fig.svg`. Why isn't it  exproted to pdf format? Any ideas how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the setup. The following code is working fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgsetup{inkscapeexe=inkscape, inkscapearea=drawing, inkscapeversion=1}
\svgpath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This code allows for automatically including of files made on Inkscape? Even with the text and all? That's neat!